# Unit testing a function that is returning ValidatorFn[] type

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to write a unit test for a function that I wrote for assigning required, min and max validators to a form control. Eventually I am getting this error:

```
Expected $[1] = Function to equal Function.
```

This is my function:

```
dimensionValidatorCreator(propertyMin: number, propertyMax: number): ValidatorFn[] {
    if (propertyMin && propertyMax) {
      return [Validators.required, Validators.min(propertyMin), Validators.max(propertyMax)];
    }
  }
```

This is my test which is failing:

```
it('should return validator array including required, min and max validators', () => {
  const propertyMin: number = 1;
  const propertyMax: number = 5;

  const actual = service.dimensionValidatorCreator(propertyMin, propertyMax);
  const result = [Validators.required, Validators.min(1), Validators.max(5)];

  expect(actual).toEqual(result);
});
```

Comment: The problem is that every time you call `Validators.min(1)` you get a *new* function, which won't compare equal to others even if they have the same value.

Comment: There is no iteration here. Calling it only once in the test.

Comment: What do you mean *"iteration"*? And you're calling it *twice*; once in the test, once **in the code under test**.

Comment: That's right sorry. That's why I am trying to find exact resulting value.